# Azure Service Bus: Duplicate messages are processing in message queue

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, asp.net-core-2.1

I am working on Azure Service Bus. My service bus queue is processing one message 3 times. My lock time of message is 5 minutes. Every message is processing max of 2 mins but I don't know why the queue is picking same message and sending to processing and the duplicate messages are picking after 5 mins only.

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 2):

With Azure Service Bus messages will be re-processed when a message is not actioned by the receiving party. An action would be completing, deferring, dead-lettering. If you don't have any of those, once `LockDuration` on the broker side expires, the message will be re-delivered. Additional situation when a message would be re-delivered without waiting for `LockDuration` to time out would be to abandon a message. Then a message is picked up right away by the next request for new messages.

You should share your code to provide enough context. Messages can be received manually using `MessageReceiver.ReceiveAsync()` or using user-callback API. For the first option you have to action messages (complete for example). For the other option, there's a configuration API where you could opt-out of auto-completion and would be required manually complete message passed into user-callback.